# WAMP server taking a long time to load in the browser

Tags: wamp

I just installed WAMP server 2.4 on a Windows 7 PC.

By default, any page on localhost takes a long time to load, say 5-10 minutes.

What possible causes could be slowing down a WAMP server localhost?

Comment: Are there other processes running, such as database servers or any other services?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer was set to Automatically Detect proxy settings in the properties of the LAN Connection.

Unticking this meant localhost would load quickly.